# Video mixer from multiple sources into one

Tags: video, video-recording, screen-casting, webvideos, video-capture

I want to take two video inputs say one from camera through hdmi/dvi etc and one through laptop(some presentation running in it). One, I want to mix these two video streams and take it out as a single video with both the videos running parallely. Videos running side by side or picture in picture format. Secondly how can I webcast this video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet for this is to use streaming software.  [Open Broadcaster Software](http://obsproject.com) for example is able to take a video capture device input (such as using an HDMI capture device and an HDMI camera, or simply using a high end web cam) and combine it with a screen capture (built in feature) and turn it in to a video stream on the fly.  It can then relay this stream to a stream service of your choice, such as YouTube or you can use your own media server such as a RED 5 instance (though running your own server is far more complicated.)

Comment: @ AJ Henderson. Thanks I will explore the option suggested by you. Let me elaborate the requirement little more here. A convention need to be captured and streamed through webcasting. Now the person at the far end who would be watching this stream should be seeing two videos merged into one. One would be the screen of the laptop through which the convener is giving the presentation(Audio/Audio+Video) and the video of the whole event captured by a camera. How can we achieve this? One part is to combine the two media streams and second is to webcast the output. 1st part is more important.

Comment: OBS will do both at the same time.

Comment: You mean OBS can combine Audio/Video from a camera and mic and the audio/video of the presentation in the laptop and stream it also through webcast!

Comment: Yes, that's the entire point of the software.  You take different sources, lay them out on a stage (which lets you do the picture in picture or side by side, which ever you prefer) and it encodes the final combined video and sends it out as a stream.

Answer (score 1):

**ffmpeg** will do everything you request. It can capture both the screen and the video input, compose that to a single image, and stream it... You should look at it... Its a command line utility, but very well documented